# path of uploaded file

Tags: c#, sql

i have uploaded a file to folder named quiz and save it using

```
    server_filepath = Server.MapPath(folderName) + "\\" + fileName;
        fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(server_filepath);
cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into quiz(description) Values('" + server_filepath +  "')";
```

and save the link of uploaded file to database.

that link is displayed in another page as.

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="description" 
            DataValueField="id">
        </asp:BulletedList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:chaaapaConnectionString4 %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [quiz]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

but when click on the link the error occurs 
that is **the resource cannot be found.**

Comment: Kamran you go to your profile (click on name on top of page). Goto the questions section. click on the question you have asked. and accept that anser which you think helped you ....solve your problem. Easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saving an absolute path (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yoursite\quiz\filename.pdf) to the database.

Try saving Path.Combine(folderName, fileName) to the database, and use that as the hyperlink instead.

Comment: path is not recognized by the visual studio.is there any header file needed to add??

Comment: You'll need to add: `using System.IO;` at the top of your codebehind.